# What to do if facebook session / token is invalid in my application?

Tags: android, facebook, session

I'm a beginner with the Facebook SDK (3.0.1) for Android and I'm wondering a lot of questions that I was not able to find on the official documentation.

In the facebook example, to ask for new permissions, they are using the UILifeCyclerHelper in the same activity than the login activity. My case is a little bit different.

In my case, I log in the user in a first activity, and then, more later, I'm asking for permissions to publish on its wall.

1) I'm wondering about what to do when the session is null, closed, or in an other state that don't allow me to ask these permissions.

2) Because the publishing on the wall is do later by my server, I need to send the user access token. Here again, what can I do if this token is null / invalid ?

3) I'm currently asking permissions like bellow. What can I do to have a callback of the user's answer ? Is this happenned onActivityResult ? What kind of answers are returned ?

Per advance, thanks for your help !

```
Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

if (session != null){

// Check for publish permissions    
List<String> permissions = session.getPermissions();
if (!isSubsetOf(PERMISSIONS, permissions)) {
    Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(this, PERMISSIONS);
                session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
}

else{
     launchPublishWallTask();
}

private static final List<String> PERMISSIONS = Arrays.asList("publish_stream");
private boolean isSubsetOf(Collection<String> subset, Collection<String> superset) {
    for (String string : subset) {
        if (!superset.contains(string)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

---

EDIT (to answer to Ming Li's answer) :

Thanks for your answer... but there is some points that I don't understand again.

1) If my session is null, do you say to simply do that ?

```
if (session == null){
    session = new Session(this.getSherlockActivity());
    Session.setActiveSession(session);
}
```

By doing that, the user will have to login again, no ? Permissions will disappear from this new Session object, even if user has accepted it before, isn't it ?

2) I have read that the user access token is only valid during 2 houres, and is invalidated in some case, like the user reset password for example. So, by recreating the session object (question 1 above), even if I have the session object AND permissions, is it sure that I will have a valid user access token too ?

3) OK, thanks

To resume my question, is it a good way to do "only" that in my case (I have not copy here the onActivityResult method, but it's ok for that):

```
public void onClick(View v){

        // Retrieve Facebook session object
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (session == null){
            session = new Session(this.getSherlockActivity());
            Session.setActiveSession(session);
        }
        session.addCallback(this);

        if (session != null){

            // Check for publish permissions    
            List<String> permissions = session.getPermissions();
            if (!isSubsetOf(PERMISSIONS, permissions)) {
                Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(
                    this, PERMISSIONS
                );
                session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
            }

            else{
                launchPublishWallTask();
            }

        }

}

@Override
public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {

    if (session != null && isSubsetOf(PERMISSIONS, session.getPermissions())){
        launchPublishWallTask();
    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(getSherlockActivity(), "you have to accept !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}


   private void launchPublishWallTask(){
         // Here, I'm sure that I will have a valid Session.getActiveSession().getAccessToken() .. or not ?
   }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use UiLifecycleHelper in any activity you want, just create a new one (it will automatically start using the active session). If you're using the active session, then it's a static that's preserved across all of your Activity instances, so you can access it from any activity simply by calling Session.getActiveSession(). As long as one of your activities have opened the session, you can use it in another activity.

1. If your session is null, just create a new one and set it as the active session (or call one of the openActiveSession() methods). If the user has authorized your app already, it will go straight to the opened state** and you'll be able to use it. Same thing if it's closed. If the user hasn't authorized your app yet, both session.isOpened and session.isClosed will return false and you should probably redirect them to your login activity.
2. I'm not quite sure how to answer this question. If you don't have an access token, then you'll need to open a session and get the publish permissions. Now way to really get around that.
3. Yes, any time you open a session or request new permissions from an activity or fragment, you must override the onActivityResult, and pass through everything up to the session that you're acting against. The session will then call your StatusCallback that you registered with it (or the UiLifecycleHelper).

** Note: it will only auto-open if it has cached data (which the SDK automatically saves). However, if you call session.closeAndClearTokenInformation, then the cache will be cleared, and it will prompt the user to authorize again.

EDIT - to answer further questions:

1. Yes, you can use that. If the user has logged in previously, the session will auto-populate using the cached data and go immediately into the OPENED state (as long as you haven't called closeAndClearTokenInformation in the past). All your permissions/access token are preserved. You can also use the [Session.openActiveSessionFromCache](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/Session#openActiveSessionFromCache%28Context%29) method, and if that returns null, that means we can't create an open session from cache (for any number of reasons), and you should prompt the user to re-login.
2. By default, user access tokens last 60 days (I believe), and if you make your graph requests using the Request class provided by the SDK, it will auto-extend the tokens for you if they're expired. If the user changes their password or removes your app (or a number of other things), the access token will become invalid, and they MUST re-login and reauthorize your app. See [this page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/errors/) on how to handle common errors.
3. That looks fine. You'll want to make sure that the session you created is in the opened state first before calling requestNewPublishPermissions though.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I have edited my post to answer you :)

Comment: I still have a problem with this solution : the call method is called to early in the fragment lifecycle. Indeed, if the fragment has been destroyed, when the call method is called, getSherlockActivity.getContext() returns null ! How to solve that ?